# Angular2: Stream videos present in AWS S3 | Cross Origin error

Tags: java, angular, amazon-s3, html5-video, amazon-cloudfront

My application requires video files present in S3 to be played on frontend but seems like it is not able to read it. The error on browser console says:

```
Cross-Origin Request Blocked: The Same Origin Policy disallows reading the remote resource at https://s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/mybucket/Oct17/myvideo.mov. (Reason: CORS header 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' missing).
All candidate resources failed to load. Media load paused.
```

The component where am loading the video is:

```
<video #media [vgMedia]="media" id="singleVideo" preload="auto" crossorigin>
  <source src="https://s3-eu-west-1.amazonaws.com/mybucket/Oct17/myvideo.mov" type="video/mp4">
</video>
```

Now, this is just one video but I have a db mapping which contains these S3 video urls which are upload using `awscli` copy command to a folder. There are plenty of videos under different folders inside `mybucket`. For one or two videos, am able to publish them using `AWS CloudFront` and when I give that URL under `src` attribute, the video plays fine.

Any idea how to stream these videos via S3 url or how should I create the `CloudFront` url for all the videos uploaded?

Answer (score 0):

You need to enable cross origin resource sharing in S3. [This](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/user-guide/add-cors-configuration.html) describes how to do that.

Here's a simple policy, which enables GET requests.

```
 <CORSConfiguration>
    <CORSRule>
        <AllowedOrigin>*</AllowedOrigin>
        <AllowedMethod>GET</AllowedMethod>
        <MaxAgeSeconds>3000</MaxAgeSeconds>
        <AllowedHeader>Authorization</AllowedHeader>
    </CORSRule>
</CORSConfiguration>
```